# How do I count the number of items in certain intervals?

Tags: java

I am writing a program in javafx that reads and visualize the data from the 2015 Vancouver property tax report. It's in a csv format.

I want to count the number of properties within intervals that increments by $25,000. For example the minimum value would be $100,000 and from there it increases by $25,000. The maximum property value in the entire data set is around a billion dollars. I ruled out switches and ifs because I believe it would take a long time to complete.

Is there a shorter method in java that can do this? I am using Java 8.

Comment: start by this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, but all you need is a Map<Integer, Integer>, where the key is the lower bound of the interval (100,000, 125,000, 150,000, etc.), and the value is the count for that interval. For each property, remove the modulo of its value (let's say 157,000) divided by 25,000 (which thus leads to the lower bound 150,000), and increment the corresponding count.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for responding? Can you please tell me what is unclear? I would like to avoid this mistake in the future. In the current land value column there are around 200K rows of data. I wanted to count the number of properties within certain intervals. I thought using ifs and switches would be time consuming so I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of searching through these intervals.

Comment: In general, you should always post the code you tried. Posting example inputs and outputs also helps understanding what you want. All you say is that you ruled out ifs and switches, but I can't even understand how ifs and switches would help solving your problem, and why they would be inherently slow.

Comment: Not slow but time consuming. As I said the minimum is 100,000 and increments by 25,000. The maximum value is in the billions so using ifs and switches to count for values in those intervals would take a long time.

Comment: ifs or switches could be used to detect ranges e.g. `if (val > 100000 && val < 125000)`
using ifs like that would result in approx 4x maxval/25000 statements

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array (or maybe better yet, a map) that holds the count of each house.

For example, using an array:

```
int[] houseArray = new int[1+((max_house_value-100000)/25000)];
for (int price : houses_price_array){
  if (price < 100000){
    houseArray[0] += 1;
  } else {
    houseArray[((price-100000)/25000)+1] += 1;//int rounds down, need +1
  }
}
```